# FragmentCompat restarts app

Tags: android

```
int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
int contactsDisabled = getActivity().checkCallingPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);

if (apiLevel >= 23 && contactsDisabled != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(SaleFragment.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

When my request permission popups on the screen in my fragment and when I press allow the application restarts.  If I press deny the request permission keeps popping back up and will only go away if I press allow.  Can anyone suggests a fix for this?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are using the AppCompat library but still using the direct activity's permission check call. I've not encountered the specific behavior you are experiencing, but this is how I implemented the run-time permissions for my app and it works correctly using `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`

```
int contactsDisabled = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);

if (apiLevel >= 23 && contactsDisabled != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(SaleFragment.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: I am using android:support-v13 library 23+ for FragmentCompat library to work in my fragment classes.  I have tried using the v4-support library with AppCompat in it..  I tried as you explained with the ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission and zero is returned when contacts is actually disabled.